# func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) is not called

Tags: draw, swift3, nsview

I wrote this code in Swift 3.0 but draw method is not called from func drawBorder by needsDisplay = true; drawBorder is called by clicking button in another view.
Thanks for any hint.

```
class clsDrawView: NSView {

    private var redraw = false
    var border = NSBezierPath()
    var color = NSColor()

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
        if redraw {
            color.setStroke()
            border.stroke()
        }
    }

    func drawBorder() {
        redraw = true
        color = NSColor.blue
        border.lineWidth = CGFloat(10)
        border.move(to: NSPoint(x: 20, y: 20))
        border.line(to: NSPoint(x: 50, y: 50))

        needsDisplay = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it via notification

```
class clsDrawView: NSView {

private var draw = false
private var border = NSBezierPath()
var color = NSColor()

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.drawBorder(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "drawBorder"), object: nil)

    // Drawing code here.
    if draw {
        color.setStroke()
        border.stroke()
    }
}

func drawBorder(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    draw = true
    color = NSColor.black
    NSBezierPath.setDefaultLineWidth(4)
    border.lineWidth = CGFloat(10)
    border = NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
    needsDisplay = true
}   
}
```

Notification is postec from ViewController like this

```
@IBAction func btnDraw(_ sender: NSButton) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "drawBorder"), object: sender)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `setNeedsDisplay(_:)` method on your view, this should call `draw(_:)` method. Never call `draw(_:)` method by yourself.

Comment: Instead of needsDisplay property try call setNeedsDisplay() in drawBorder method.

Comment: I don`t call draw(_:) I just set needsDisplay = true which should ensure calling draw(_:). I have suspicion that it's because I call drawBorder by button click outside of the custom view. If I call it from                          **override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        drawBorder()
}** then it works perfectly.

Comment: I added setNeedsDisplay(self.bounds) and no change. Note that setNeedsDisplay(InvalidRect: NSRect) need argument in Swift 3

Comment: Ok. I tested it in playgroud. Try to remove "if" condition from draw method.

Comment: Well, then it crashes at launching the app.

Comment: Hmm I have no idea :/ The fact is that your condition will be always false when you redraw the view..

Comment: Maybe you can call the "setStroke" method in drawBorder?